# Azure Standard Logic App Workflow Triggers Multiple Times For a Single Request Via APIM

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

Azure Standard Logic App Workflow Triggers Multiple Times For a Single Request Via APIM.

In my scenario I need to trigger a workflow once a user hits the APIM API link sent to the user via an email, what I have noticed is though the user sends only one request via link APIM is triggering my workflow multiple times. Just for information my Standard Logic App resides in a VNet.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Standard Logic App Workflow Triggers Multiple Times For a Single Request Via APIM

This problem can occur if you use a polling trigger in APIM. Polling Trigger's functionality is that it checks for latest data on a regular basis (in specific time intervals).

If you don't want your Logic app to be triggered frequently, you can change your APIM to use Event Based Trigger.

If you want to handle requests from the outside sources, you can use a webhook trigger.

One reason could be due to Vnet as well, as there could be some delay in receiving requests or multiple time triggering.

This can also occur as a result of multiple retries, APIM request duplication, or a Logic app configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. While my Workflow was not on the VNet, it had multiple conditions/decisions, which would stop/terminate the workflow in the middle. While Response action is mandatory for a workflow to be invoked from another workflow, I only had one response action at the end.
I managed to solve this by adding additional "Response" action to every branch that would stop the workflow in the middle. For some reason, if a workflow is invoked from another, it tries to trigger it multiple times until the "Response" is reached. Someone can correct me on this, but this is what I have noticed while testing my solution